# How do I set up a RAID 0 on windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, raid

I have a windows 8 machine with a 2T internal hard drive and 12G of ram. I have an external WD 3T that automatically backs up my entire I tunes 
Ibrary. I have added a second 2T internal drive and want to set it up as RAID 0 in hopes that the external will continue to auto back up my growing iTunes library. I use my computer basically as media storage playing in multiple rooms on Apple TVs.

Comment: Do you have a hardware raid controller or raid software?  If your motherboard has a raid controller check that for directions on setting up the raid this involves installing the operating system again

Comment: "I have added a second 2T internal drive and want to set it up as RAID 0" with what as its teammate? Because the way things are worded now in the question, it looks like your just going to set yourself up for (at the least) problems.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will have to reinstall windows IF you want to take the EASY "quicker" way. + Copy all the data and reinstall software.

How ever I can point you toward this handy site which will allow you to do RAID0 WITHOUT REINSTALLING WINDOWS. credits to "higherdensity". It is not for the average user, recommend computer enthusiast which knows about computer boot process and SATA MODES.

**SITE:** http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?72309-How-to-switch-to-RAID-0-without-reinstalling!

**Trivia:** Guide is kinda old but will still most likely apply to most computers built after 2012. Make sure you are familiar with windows 8.

BTW: I have 2 SSD's in Raid0 - It is worth every hardship.. well idn bout hdd